# Displaying values from a Dictionary within a Dictionary within MVC Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dictionary

I'm not even sure this is possible with MVC Razor, but I would like to pass my Dictionary that includes another Dictionary to my view and display the child Dictionary keys and values.

```
public Dictionary<int, dynamic> Getdata(DateInfo dataInfo)
{

//Create a parent dictionary
Dictionary<int, dynamic> parentDict = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>();

//Load the child dictionary
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
     //Create a child dictionary to store all values
     Dictionary<int, dynamic> dict = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>();

     parentDict[i] = dict;
     parentDict[i].Clear();
    if (beginningYear < DateTime.Now.Year)
    {
         //...code left out for brevity

        if (NumberOfYears > 1)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < NumberOfYears; j++)
            {
               beginningYear = beginningYear + 1;

               //...code left out for brevity

               dict.Add(beginningYear, new { Month = 12, MonthlyAmount = nextYearAmount.premium, TotalYearAmount = TotalYearAmount });
            }
        }
     else
     {
         //...code left out for brevity
     }
}
return parentDict;
```

My Parent Dictionary values looks like this:

```
[0] = {[0, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Object]]}

[1] = {[1, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Object]]}
```

My Child Dictionary values like this:

```
[0] { Month = 5, MonthlyAmount = 99.90, TotalYearAmount = 499.50 }

[1] { Month = 12, MonthlyAmount = 399.90, TotalYearAmount = 1499.50 }

[2] { Month = 12, MonthlyAmount = 499.90, TotalYearAmount = 1794.50 }
```

---

```
[0] { Month = 9, MonthlyAmount = 999.90, TotalYearAmount = 6499.50 }

[1] { Month = 12, MonthlyAmount = 3.90, TotalYearAmount = 39.50 }
```

Within the view:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.MyDictionary[0])
 { 
     @item.Value
 }
```

That code will display the child value, which is:

```
 { Month = 5, MonthlyAmount = 99.90, TotalYearAmount = 499.50 }
```

Is it possible to reference Month, MonthlyAmount, TotalYearAmount?

```
     @item.Value.Month
```

will not work.  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Month'

And I would like to go through the parent dictionary to reference the child.  If I use:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.MyDictionary[1])
 { 
     @item.Value
 }
```

That will display

```
 { Month = 9, MonthlyAmount = 999.90, TotalYearAmount = 6499.50 }
```

This code will not work, but I would like to get the values such as:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.MyDictionary[0][1])
 { 
     @item.Value.TotalYearAmount 
 }
```

and the value displays:  1499.50

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a complete example for the Razor template including Model type definition?

Comment: If you make a class that has Month, MonthlyAmount, and TotalYearAmount members instead of using an anonymous type, @item.Value.Month will work.  Is there a reason not to replace the anonymous type with a class?

Comment: @Jerry Federspiel Add that as an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line

```
dict.Add(beginningYear, new { Month = 12, MonthlyAmount = nextYearAmount.premium, TotalYearAmount = TotalYearAmount });
```

with usage of [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to

```
dynamic expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
expandoObject.Month = 12;
expandoObject.MonthlyAmount = nextYearAmount.premium;
expandoObject.TotalYearAmount = TotalYearAmount;
dict.Add(beginningYear, expandoObject);
```

If your Dictionary is longer, you can use following link to convert it in a method: http://theburningmonk.com/2011/05/idictionarystring-object-to-expandoobject-extension-method/

Comment: Interesting...so how would I reference my dictionary within my View?

Comment: Just like you have written: `@item.Value.TotalYearAmount`

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've never heard of the ExpandoObject class.  I got my code working.....(it's kinda ugly), but for what I'm doing you helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dynamic` instead of `var` like this:

```
 @foreach (dynamic item in Model.MyDictionary[0][1])
 { 
     @item.Value.TotalYearAmount 
 }
```